# TypeScript problems in webstorm using the "import" statement

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When I tried using the import statement in webstorm with TypeScript enabled I get the error

> Error:(14, 1) TS1148: Cannot compile external modules unless the '--module' flag is provided.

However if I add the `--module` flag to the TypeScript command line options under "webstorm Preferences -> Languages and Frameworks -> Typescript", I get the compiler cannot start error.

What's the best way to configure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--module` option requires module type (either `'--module amd'` or `'--module commonjs'`)

Please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-compiler for more information about typescript compiler arguments